# Setting up a theme using use-package

Tags: themes, use-package

I'm doing a new setup so that I can have an init.el on my dropbox as a one stop shop for my configuration. So far so good but I'm stuck on the theme.

When I setup the code using load-path it all works like it should, all the colors and the modeline. My question is how can I do the same but using the use-package approach?

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")

(setq molokai-theme-kit t)
(load-theme 'molokai t)
```

Is something like this possible?

```
(use-package molokai-theme 
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq molokai-theme-kit t)
  (load-theme 'molokai t)
  )
```

Answer (score 5):

My **user-emacs-directory** points to a folder on my Dropbox.
Apparently **use-package :load-path** points to the **user-emacs-directory** by default, I just had to put "themes" and the necessary files inside it.

It's now working like a charm.

```
(use-package molokai-theme 
  :ensure t
  :load-path "themes"
  :init
  (setq molokai-theme-kit t)
  :config
  (load-theme 'molokai t)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `:defer t` in the use-package declaration too.

Comment: Thanks for answering but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add this to your init.el but I recomend you to create a init.el in your home directory, and make this file to load the one you have in dropbox. So yo create a file wich have the following content:

```
(load-file "<your-path-to-dropbox>/yourdropboxinit.el")
```

I think this is the better solution for you.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you keep your `init.el` under version control either publicly in Github or privately in BitBucket.

Also, have you considered using the community-driven Emacs distribution called [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs)?

Adjusting themes is particularly [easy](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/theming) in Spacemacs, and there is a vast [vast number](http://themegallery.robdor.com/) of themes to choose from.